# In C storing values that start with zero get mutated, why?

Tags: c, int, storage

For example:

```
int main(){

    int x = 01234567;

    printf("\n%d\n",x);

    return 0;

}
```

The following code produces: 342391

If I didn't include the 0 at the beginning, the value x would be 1234567, why does C store the value this way and is there any way to get it from not doing this?

Answer (score 13):

Because numbers starting with 0 are represented as [octal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). You cannot really modify this behavior, simply do not include the zero at the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

Numeric constants beginning with a 0 are interpreted as base 8.

Answer (score 7):

Integer constants written with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal (base-8), not decimal (base-10). This is analogous to `0x` triggering hexadecimal (base-16) interpretation.

Basically all you can do here is not put leading 0s on your integer constants.

Answer (score 5):

At compile time a C compiler will identify any integer literals in your code and then interpret these via a set of rules to get their binary value for use by your program:

- Base-16 (Hexadecimal) - Any integer literals beginning with '0x' will be treated as a hexadecimal value. So `int x = 0x22` gives `x` the decimal value of `2 * 16^1 + 2 * 16^0 = 34`.
- Base-8 (Octal) - Any integer literals beginning with '0' will be treated as an octal value. So `int x = 022` gives `x` the decimal value of `2 * 8^1 + 2 * 8^0 = 18`.
- Base-10 (Decimal) - Any integer literals not matching the other two rules will be treated as a decimal value. So `int x = 22` gives `x` the decimal value of `22`.

It should be noted that GCC [supports an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html) which provides another rule for specifying integers in binary format. Additionally, these methods of specification are only supported for integer literals at compile time.