# How store a number starting with 0 in C

Tags: c

Id just thought id ask this question to see whether it can actually be done.

if i want to store a number like "00000000000001", What would be the best way?
bearing in mind that this also has to be incrememted on a regular basis.

Im thinking either there is a way to do this with the integer or i have to convert to a char array somewhere along the line. This would be fine but its a pain to try and increment a string.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245841/in-c-storing-values-that-start-with-zero-get-mutated-why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should simply store the number using an appropriate type (say, `unsigned int`), so that doing operations like 'increment by one' are easy - only bother worrying about leading zeros when displaying the number.

`sprintf` can actually do this for you:

```
unsigned int i = 1;
char buffer[64];
sprintf( buf, "%014u", i );
```

This prints '00000000000001'.

Comment: I should have said this before but it needs to be put in a table field that is a string, or char* [].

Comment: @spartan2417 that's what `sprintf` is for

Comment: @David Heffernan: Good point, I used '14' now as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @spartan2417: I now updated the code sample to use `sprintf`, which you can use to render the string into a `char` buffer.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Good point, I incorporated your comment into the source code now.

Comment: You would have to use %014ld, %014lld etc since the plain int type most likely doesn't support numbers with 14 digits on any platform.

Comment: @Lundin: `%ld` must match the type of the argument.  The type of the argument is `unsigned int`, so the correct specifier is %u whether or not `unsigned int` is capable of storing 14 digit integers.

Comment: @JeremyP Yeah but the unsigned int was something made up by this poster and not a requirement stated by the OP.

Answer (score 8):

I would store it as an integer and only convert to the formatted version with leading zeros on demand when you need to produce output, for example with `printf`, `sprintf` etc.

It's far easier that way than storing a string and trying to perform arithmetic on strings. Not least because you have extra formatting requirements about your strings.

If for some reason it is awkward to store an integer as your master data do it like this.

1. Store the string as your master data.
2. Whenever you need to perform arithmetic, convert from string to integer.
3. When the arithmetic is complete, convert back to string and store.

Comment: +1 from me, simply because you descrieb the same apprach as I did in my answer. So if my answer is useful (which I consider it to be), so is yours. :-)

Comment: You would have to use %014ld, %014lld etc since the plain int type most likely doesn't support numbers with 14 digits on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

You could store it in a integer variable (provided there's an integer type that's wide enough for your needs). When printing, simply format the number to have the correct number of leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for itoa() call
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf() call

int main() {
    int num = 123;
    char buf[5];

    // convert 123 to string [buf]
    itoa(num, buf, 10);

    // print our string
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `itoa` is non-standard and nowhere do you deal with leading zeros. Since you call `printf` which can convert integers to text, and add leading zeros, surely easiest to do the work there.

Comment: +1 from me simply for the comments after the `#include`s. I often do the same to figure out why I once included something (chances are - I don't need the header anymore).

Comment: -1 for not mentioning that itoa is non-standard. It is not found in stdlib.h in a conforming implementation of C.